# Unable to pull Puppet Forge modules with r10k

Tags: puppet, puppetmaster, r10k

I have what appears to be a functioning r10k setup with respect to publishing branches as environments, but when I run the command to pull modules via

```
sudo /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/bin/r10k deploy environment -p -v
```

I get

```
INFO     -> Deploying environment /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production
INFO     -> Environment production is now at cd62f3bb36117b1418672a1039b8212aa8bb36dd
INFO     -> Deploying Puppetfile content /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules/ntp
ERROR    -> stream error
INFO     -> Deploying Puppetfile content /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules/stdlib
ERROR    -> stream error
```

My /etc/puppetlabs/r10k/r10k.yaml

```
:cachedir: '/var/cache/r10k'

# A list of git repositories to create
:sources:
  :operations:
    remote: 'git@git:sysops/puppet.git'
    basedir: '/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments'
```

My Puppetfile

```
forge 'forge.puppetlabs.com'

mod 'puppetlabs/ntp', '4.1.0'
mod 'puppetlabs/stdlib'
```

Neither of those seem relevant to me, just thought I'd add them to preempt that question. If I do a packet capture of HTTPS on my puppet host I get a bunch of outbound traffic like this

```
15:19:14.507310 IP puppet.domain.net.33955 > ec2-52-10-130-237.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com.https: Flags [.], ack 17926, win 545, options [nop,nop,TS val 129210401 ecr 2944333247], length 0
```

and a bunch of inbound like

```
15:19:14.520146 IP ec2-52-10-130-237.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com.https > puppet.domain.net.33955: Flags [.], seq 20822:22270, ack 628, win 227, options [nop,nop,TS val 2944333252 ecr 129210401], length 1448
```

So things are communicating, but still the fairly useless "stream error" from r10k. If you turn up debugging with `-v debug2` you get the same messages on the modules, just a bunch before and a bunch after.

This is a similar question to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35712872/r10k-ruby-connection-error-to-the-forge but that question was marked as solved without actually being solved, so not a duplicate IMO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that while the ruby rugged module is being built(which is a r10k dependency) it's using zlib symbols compiled in libgit2 instead of those provided by the operating system. For me, it was enough to remove rugged module gem, install zlib-devel package on the system and install rugged again.

```
gem uninstall rugged
yum install zlib-devel
gem install rugged
```

If you want to confirm your problem is the same, just run the code below in the ruby console(irb):

```
require 'rugged'
require 'zlib'
Zlib::Inflate.new(32 + Zlib::MAX_WBITS)
```

It should raise a Zlib::StreamError.

Sources that led me to this soulution:

https://github.com/prontolabs/pronto/issues/23

https://github.com/libgit2/rugged/issues/705

Comment: I'd given up on this a long time ago but that fixes it, I guess I can give it another go. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same, I'm using packages from PC1 on Ubuntu 16.04, but r10k is running off system Ruby. It seems like the vague "stream error" comes from one of the Ruby gem dependencies which is why verbosity in r10k doesn't give any more useful output.